# VBA code to select from an HTML drop down (SELECT tag and OPTIONS tags) with event code

Tags: html, vba, html-parsing

everybody.
I'm studying VBA grabbing of HTML websites.
I found a strange situation that I don't as well as deal with. It is a WEB page that contains a drop-down box that allows the display of all the information in a table. The page is the following: [enter link description here](https://www.discogs.com/it/LOrchestre-Symphonique-De-Montreal-Charles-Dutoit-Hector-Berlioz-Berlioz-Masterworks/release/10769738).
As you can see, the options allow to view 25, 50 or all the tracks on the disc.
So, if I load the page for analysis, and then programmatically look for the table's lines (Tags ), I find 53. These are the relevant lines of the VBA code:

- **Load HTML page** -

```
Sub CreaHTML()
On Error GoTo erroriHTML
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
  .Open "GET", sAppoggio, False
  .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
  .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101Firefox /25.0"
  .send
  Do While .ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Pausa (2)
  Loop
  sHTM = .responseText
End With
Set ohtm = New HTMLDocument
ohtm.body.innerHTML = sHTM
Exit Sub
```

- **page analysis** -

```
Call CreaHTML
'Call test1
Set oOggetto = ohtm.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
If oOggetto Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set tbls = oOggetto.getElementsByTagName("tr")
'Debug.Print tbls.length
If tbls.length = 0 Then Exit Sub
```

I leave out the other parts of the code.
To try to enable the presence of all tracks, I wrote this routine which should select the *Option* :

```
 Sub test1() Dim dropOptions As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection Set
 dropOptions = ohtm.getElementsByTagName("option") For Each elem2 In
 dropOptions Debug.Print elem2.Value
     If elem2.Value = "all" Then
         elem2.Selected = True
         Exit For
     End If Next
 End Sub
```

However, if I apply the routine, the number of detected  tags does not change. Yet, the routine seems to go smoothly without errors.
I think it could depends on the *event* applied in the HTML code, but I don't really know how to deal with it.
The point is, selecting the  *option* doesn't change the page url.
Can anyone give me an explanation, and / or a solution?

Comment: Use the linked answer. The data is contained with script tag with id `dsdata` so you can use `ohtm.querySelector("#dsdata").innerHTML`  to extract and then parse with json parser. The json looks like this: `https://jsoneditoronline.org/?#left=cloud.c3230f5fa9a84b728a33bea4db334eb8` The `trackType` will tell you if a track or one of the headers.

Comment: The path to the collection of dictionaries you need to loop over is `json►data►Release:{"discogsId":10769738}►tracks►` where json is `Set json = jsonConverter.ParseJson(ohtm.querySelector("#dsdata").innerHTML)`